# releasing rooms after check out of user in a hotel reservation system using rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

In my hotel reservation system i have a rooms table which has 4 types of rooms, associated with a particular hotel. When i book the rooms e.g. if i book 2 single bedrooom and 1 double bedroom then the available rooms gets subtracted. My problem is when the user checks out i.e. if check out date >= today then i want to retrieve the booked rooms back. How can i do that.
this is my association:

```
class Booking < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :user
  validate :check_out_greater_than_check_in
end

class Hotel < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :room, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :bookings
    belongs_to :city
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    scope :search_it, ->(s_term) { where("name LIKE ? OR city LIKE ?", "%#{s_term}%", "%#{s_term}%") }
    has_attached_file :picture, styles: {large: "500x500>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "150x150#"}
    validates_attachment_content_type :picture, content_type: %r{\Aimage\/.*\z}
    validates_attachment_presence :picture
end

class Room < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
end
```

This is my bookings controller:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :current_hotel, except: [:new]
  after_action :alter_rooms, only: [:create]

  def new
    @booking = Booking.new
    @single = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", params[:hotel_id]).pluck(:single_bedroom_num)
    @s = @single[0].to_i
    @double = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", params[:hotel_id]).pluck(:double_bedroom_num)
    @d = @double[0].to_i
    @suite = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", params[:hotel_id]).pluck(:suite_room_num)
    @sui = @suite[0].to_i
    @dormitory = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", params[:hotel_id]).pluck(:dormitory_room_num)
    @dor = @dormitory[0].to_i
    s = params[:single_bedroom_num]
    d = params[:double_bedroom_num]
    su = params[:suite_room_num]
    dor = params[:dormitory_room_num]
    session[:hotel_id] = params[:hotel_id]
    @hotel = current_hotel
  end

  def index
  end

  def create
    @hotel = current_hotel.id
    @booking = @hotel.bookings.build(book_params)
    if signed_in?
      params[:user_id] = current_user
    else
      authorize 
    end
    if @booking.save
      flash.now.alert = "booked successfully!"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Oops, couldn't book."
      render :new
    end

  end

  def show
    @hotel = Hotel.find(params[:hotel_id])
    check_in = params[:check_in_date]
    check_out = params[:check_out_date]
    @single = Room.single_bedroom_num
    @booking = Booking.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def book_params
    params.require(:booking).permit(:id, :num_of_guests, :guest_name, :check_in_date, :check_out_date, :single_bedroom_num, :double_bedroom_num, :suite_room_num, :dormitory_room_num, :hotel_name, :hotel_id, :user_id)
  end
  def current_hotel
    @current_hotel ||= Hotel.find(session[:hotel_id])
  end
  def alter_rooms

    @single = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", session[:hotel_id]).pluck(:single_bedroom_num)
    s = @single[0].to_i
    @double = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", session[:hotel_id]).pluck(:double_bedroom_num)
    d = @double[0].to_i
    @suite = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", session[:hotel_id]).pluck(:suite_room_num)
    sui = @suite[0].to_i
    @dormitory = Room.joins(:hotel).where("hotel_id = ?", session[:hotel_id]).pluck(:dormitory_room_num)
    dor = @dormitory[0].to_i

    @so = @booking.single_bedroom_num
    s_new = @so.to_i
    @duo = @booking.double_bedroom_num
    d_new = @duo.to_i
    @suio = @booking.suite_room_num
    sui_new = @suio.to_i
    @doro = @booking.dormitory_room_num
    dor_new = @doro.to_i
    h_id = @booking.hotel_id.to_i

    s_res = (s - s_new).to_i
    d_res = (d - d_new).to_i
    sui_res = (sui - sui_new).to_i
    dor_res = (dor - dor_new).to_i
    @room = Room.find_by(hotel_id: h_id)
    @room.update_attributes(single_bedroom_num: s_res, double_bedroom_num: d_res, suite_room_num: sui_new, dormitory_room_num: dor_new )
  end

end
```

Comment: I don't see any checkout action, you are using `create` to book room, fine, but how does user checkout, you have to share checkout code, also I don't see you are have done anywhere checkin boolean, like if guest check in any room, than there should be boolean field which will be 0 for free 1 for booked.

Comment: my schema is different i am subtracting the no. of single rooms or double rooms a user is booking from the room table

Comment: I can use active jobs to release the booked rooms but i dont know how

Comment: yes I just noticed you are subtracting in your alter_room function. Where do you release/cancel or amend bookings? I can't find any method, you have to put your job in that method, so whenever that method is called a job is setup, within your job you can put code to add room quantity.

Comment: ```  def restore_rooms
    h_id = @booking.hotel_id.to_i
    ReleaseRoomsCheckoutJob.set(wait_until: Date.today <= Booking.joins(:user).pluck(:check_out_date)).perform_now(h_id)
  end
```

Comment: this is giving an error:

Comment: comparison of Date with Array failed